# Antlr 4.6.1 not generating errorNodes for inputstream

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a simple grammar like :

```
grammar CellMath;

equation : expr EOF;

expr 
    :  '-'expr                  #UnaryNegation      // unary minus
    |   expr op=('*'|'/') expr  #MultiplicativeOp   // MultiplicativeOperation
    |   expr op=('+'|'-') expr  #AdditiveOp         // AdditiveOperation
    |   FLOAT                   #Float              // Floating Point Number
    |   INT                     #Integer            // Integer Number
    |   '(' expr ')'            #ParenExpr          // Parenthesized Expression
    ;

MUL :   '*' ;
DIV :   '/' ;
ADD :   '+' ;
SUB :   '-' ;

FLOAT
    :   DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT*
    |   '.' DIGIT+ 
    ;

INT :    DIGIT+ ;

fragment
DIGIT : [0-9] ; // match single digit

//fragment
//ATSIGN : [@];

WS :     [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

ERRORCHAR : . ;
```

Not able to throw an exception in case of special char in between expression

[{Number}{SPLChar}{Chars}]
Ex:
"123@abc",
"123&abc".

I expecting an exception to throw

For Example:
**Input stream : 123@abc** Just like in ANTLR labs [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZrXK.png)

But in my case **Output : '123' without any errors**

I'm using Listener pattern, Error nodes are just ignored not going through VisitTerminal([NotNull] ITerminalNode node) / VisitErrorNode([NotNull] IErrorNode node) in the BaseListener class. Also all the BaseErrorListener class methods has been overridden not even there.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What target is this? CSharp or Java or what? Note, there's no 4.6.1 Antlr Tool .jar file in the downloads directory. https://github.com/antlr/website-antlr4/tree/gh-pages/download , in Maven Central, only in Nuget.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Antlr4.Runtime.Standard v4.6, CSharp target. (Defined the VisitErrorNode() method in your listener class. `public class Foo : ArithmeticBaseListener { public override void VisitErrorNode([NotNull] IErrorNode node) { System.Console.WriteLine("Err node "+ node.GetText()); } }` and walked with `var vis = new Foo(); var w = new ParseTreeWalker(); w.Walk(vis, tree);`.)

Comment: @kaby76 Target is Csharp

Comment: @kaby76 - [![Version of Antlr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRCuM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRCuM.png)

Comment: @kaby76 Here Parser itself not generating nodes/errors for me. [Sample code for issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilxoT.png)] In this image 'CellMathParser' is the Antlr generated class.

Comment: Here's what it should look like. https://github.com/kaby76/so74642814 The code works, error nodes are printed. `dotnet build; ./bin/Debug/net6.0/Test.exe -input '123@abc' -tokens`. Also, you should be using the official Antlr4 tool and code, not an unsupported fork--and a 6 year old version of it at that.

Comment: Here is the solution. Instead of using **parser.expr()** replaced it with **parser.equation()** without updating Antlr version. Now I see all the nodes that are supposed to generate.

Comment: Unless you know what you are doing, always start the parse using a rule which has an EOF symbol at the end of the rule.